# Hausdorff-measure

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $\Omega:=\mathbb{R}^n$. For a subset $A\subset\Omega$ the expression $\lvert A\rvert:=\sup\left\{\lvert x-y\rvert:x,y\in A\right\}$ is called the diameter of $A$. For $M\in\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ and $s\geq 0, \delta>0$ we define
> >     $$
> > H_{\delta}^s(M):=\inf\left\{\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\lvert U_i\rvert^s\forall~i\in\mathbb{N}: U_i\subset\Omega,\lvert U_i\rvert <\delta,i\in\mathbb{N}: M\subset\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}U_i\right\},\\
> > H^s(M):=\lim_{\delta\downarrow 0}H_{\delta}^s(M). (*)
> > $$
> >     Show that the limit in (*) does exist! And that $H_{\delta}^s$ and $H^s$ are outer measures.

Could you please tell me how to show that the limit exists or at least give me a hint how to show that?

Comment: is there some missing assumption, such as $M$ is compact, or bounded?

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the first part (showing the limit exists): I am pretty sure $H^s_\delta$ is a monotone function of $\delta$ (in addition to being nonnegative).  Note: making $\delta$ smaller means you are taking the $\inf$ of a smaller (or no larger) set of real numbers.  The behavior of monotone functions of real numbers is severely limited.  I'm making this an "answer" because it might be enough for the OP (s/he wrote "or at least give me a hint").

EDIT: though the limit must exist, the definition given admits the possibility that the limit is $\infty$:  for example take $M=\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $0\leq s\leq n$.

Comment: I think you should give a hint on how to find an upper bound, which is not trivial.

Comment: @user32240 : I don't think there has to be an upper bound.  See the edit to my answer.  And the question did not ask how to show there is a finite upper bound (in the case where one exists).

Comment: @user32240 : the definition said nothing about $M$ other than $M \subset \Omega$.

Comment: I think then it missed the point of the exercise. One should be able to prove for compact sets the measure is finite.

Comment: @user32240 : of course the finiteness of the limit also depends on $s$, which is not specified either